# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+

Tags: java, android

i am working in my own application and 
it was working fine but suddenly the grade could not be sync 
and i am sure i did not change anything , 
***Grade***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.am.ahmad"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.20"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note that it was work fine but now the problem is this line

```
        compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
```

Best

Comment: Please don't use plusses in library versions

Comment: great thanks it worked

Comment: compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'

Comment: Also please move from compile to implementation/api dependecies.